# How to get the classes from a Binary Image Classification model with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Currently I am working on a binary classification model using Keras(version '2.6.0'). And I build simple model with three Blocks of 2D Convolution (Conv2D + ReLU + Pooling), then a finale blocks contain a Flatten, Dropout and two Dense layers. I have a small dataset of images in my disk and they are organized in a main directory like this:

```
/content/data/
.............train/
..................classA/
........................img1.jpg
........................img2.jpg
.
.
.
..................classB/
........................img1.jpg
........................img2.jpg
.
.
.
```

After the training step i have the following learning curves:
[image]
[image]

Even with the noisy behave, they seems great for me (correct me if I am wrong). No overfitting the training and the validation curves have the same behavior, and after 15 epochs I get 1 of accuracy and less than 0.2 as losses.

## Question:

When I test the model, I want to display to which classes the image belong A or B ?

I tried the following :

```
predictions = MODEL.predict(img_array)
score = np.argmax(predictions)
prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])
```

but i get the same score (0) for two different images belong to two   different classes.

I appreciate any suggestions or written documents, because the documentations at Keras didn't specified the details of this step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at this tutorial ? https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/11/image-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/

Comment: Not sure why you use 2 Dense layers?  and hence what np.argmax(predictions) be giving, in case of 1 dense layer and binary class, it will give class index not score.

Comment: @abdou_dev Thanks for the quick comment, I give it a try as described in the articles, by writing: " (cl_A, cl_B) = saved_model.predict(image)[0] "  but i got an error of " not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) ". Because the value of " Model.predict(img) " is an array [[0.9163068]] of (1, 1) shape. If there is an alternative way ? anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: What activation function are you using in your output layer? And how many neurons are in the output layer?

Comment: @A.B  For the two layers i was just testing the difference the first have some units I was varying them (Note I am testing on small dataset) with an ReLU activation and end it by an other Dense layers for units=1. So i was just testing. For the output of the model using " Model.predict(img) " the output is an array with a shape of 1 by 1.

Comment: @pavel For the output layer i used "sigmoid" function, and as i mentioned a 1 units (1 neuron).

Comment: So this is why you're getting a different result from the guide abdou_dev attached. That model uses an output dense layer with number of neurons equal to the number of classes. This is a standard practice and you should just change the final layer to have 2 neurons.

Comment: As @pavel , you should have 2 neurons in the output layer to define the result 0 or 1, because the result is binary .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
ImagePath = "YourImagePath" 
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    ImagePath, target_size=image_size
)
img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = predictions[0]
print(
    "This image is %.2f percent cat and %.2f percent dog."
    % (100 * (1 - score), 100 * score)
) # Will print on the Console
```

And this is a tutorial of Adrian Rosebrock that you can follow it for more details :

[Image classification with Keras and deep learning](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/11/image-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/)

Comment: I tried This answer, but it have no sense when it comes to differentiate between the classes.

Comment: The example was very clear it will print the percent of an image that could be cat and the percent of an image that could be dog , so the `firstScore` it will be calculated using `model.predict(img_array)` and the second will be calculated from the first ( 1 - `firstScore`) .

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what you got as an output?

Comment: After i give it another try i corrected my mistakes, and the way that was mentioned in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/ it worked finally thanks also to @pavel for underlining my mistakes.